# Alfresco Activiti Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise, alfresco-maven

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm having this issue with Alfresco Process Service where the memory is reaching the JVM limit, CPU is usually below 10%. Usually happening quicker when we make requests to the endpoint (/activiti-app/api/enterprise/tasks/query). Just wondering has anyone seen this issue before?

Config:
-Xms8g -Xmx16g

Heap dump:

```html
1 instance org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext  Retained Size 10.660 MB (97%) 
    1 instance of org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext 10.656 MB (100%) 
        67231 instances of org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext$ManagedEntityImpl 10.655 MB (99.9%) 
             67231 instances of org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry 10.653 MB (99.9%)
                67230 instances of java.lang.Object[] 10.648 MB (99.9%)
                    67230 instances of byte[] 10.609 MB (99.5%)
```

Endpoint: /activiti-app/api/enterprise/tasks/query
Request Body:
{
"appDefinitionId": null,
"sort": "created-desc",
"size": 50,
"start": 0,
"text": "",
"state": "completed"
}

References:
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final
hibernate-core-4.2.16.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.16.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final